# Not running Angular 4 applicationon from Azure properly

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

I am working on angular 4 application. It's working fine on my local machine. When I do ng serve it serves the application as http://localhost:4200. Since it's a POC project therefore, there is no api call but fetching data from assets/data.json file using services.

Now I like to deploy this site to azure. I got the dist folder as well when I ran "ng build --env=prod". I also saw the deployment succeeded message as well.

but, when I'm running the web site from azure it's not loading properly. I launched the developer tool and see lots of 404 not found messages. I also attached the screen shot.

I dont know why this site is not working properly. One more thing when I go inside the dist folder on my local machine and run the index.html page get the same error messages.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed the file is actually present on the filesystem?

Comment: Are you still set up to listen on port 4200? That won't work in an Azure Web App. Are you getting the port number from the environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid these 404 errors, you'd need to serve static JSON and WOFF files on Azure by creating a `web.config` file in your wwwroot folder and put the following MIME config there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />      
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added the lines in the web.config as you suggested but still facing the same problem where seems application is not able to access the data.json therefore, nothing is coming up on the screen.

Comment: I didn't add the web.config file to dist folder and hoping will be included automatically. Now I copied and pasted it and did the deployment once again. This time I dont see any json related error but throwing "internal server error" and nothing is coming up on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Aaron finally it worked and I don't see 404 errors now.

Comment: Thanks @AaronChen you saved my day

Comment: Awesome solution, it works fine for Angular applications deployed in Azure Web App!  no more error code 404, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the .htaccess file to your directory with the built code in /dist

Create .htaccess file and add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```