# Failed to publish ASP.NET Core Angular Project to Azure with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, azure, asp.net-core

I have a simple web application in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.5.4), Its a homepage showing 'Hello World!' from the backend.

The version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is 2.0.7.

I have following in my application:

```
|    Backend            |   Frontend (Angular)     |
|  Model, Controller    | Service, Model, Component|
```

When I run the application locally, it successfully runs. But when I publish it to my Azure web app, it fails.

diagnostic logs of web application:

```
018-05-07 13:16:38.634 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: ERROR Response {
  _body: 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.',
  status: 403,
  ok: false,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  headers: 
   Headers {
     _headers: 
      Map {
        'content-length' => [Array],
        'content-type' => [Array],
        'server' => [Array],
        'x-powered-by' => [Array],
        'date' => [Array] },
     _normalizedNames: 
      Map {
        'content-length' => 'content-length',
        'content-type' => 'content-type',
        'server' => 'server',
        'x-powered-by' => 'x-powered-by',
        'date' => 'date' } },
  type: 2,
  url: 'http://pweb-dev-ferfer.azurewebsites.net/home' }
```

I did search in SO and applied the solutions from other questions, I created the web.config as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143147/not-running-angular-4-applicationon-from-azure-properly).

I dont have the  `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as `Development` as suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911802/cannot-find-module-aspnet-webpack-when-using-dotnet-publish-in-net-core-2-0).

This is startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Model: `Home.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Home
    {
        public string msg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:`HomeController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            ViewData["RequestId"] = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Route("home")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                Home home = new Home();
                home.msg = "Hello World!";
                return Ok(home);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Failed to get message {ex}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service: `home.service.ts`

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { IHome } from '../models/Home';
@Injectable()
export class HomeService
{
    myAppUrl: string = "";
    constructor(private _http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
    }
    getMessage() {
        return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + "home").map((response: Response) => response.json());

    }
}
```

Component: `home.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from '../../services/home.service';
import { IHome } from '../../models/Home';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    home: IHome;
    constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private route: ActivatedRoute)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.homeService.getMessage().subscribe(data => this.home = <IHome>data);
    }

}
```

**Update**:

I can publish the web app if I do not use angular service. So if I ask the Home component to use home.service for fetching the msg, the publish fails.

This is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "WebApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you declared your service in app.module.ts in providers for Dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Azure ASP.NET Core Runtime is not yet upgraded to 2.0.7. One solution is to downgrade your Microsoft.NETCore.App package to 2.0.6 or wait until Azure services will update their Core Runtime.

Comment: new insights: I can publish the web app if I do not use angular service. as soon as I tell the component to use home.service for fetching the msg, the publish fails. do you still think that the version might cause this issue? @aMerkuri