# Angular app unable to find asset files on Azure

Tags: angular, azure

I've just deployed my angular app to azure by running an ng build --prod and pushing it to git but I get a 404 error saying that it cannot find my json file I have in the assets folder.

I've also tried running ng build --prod --base-href "./" but I'm till getting the same error.

I'm currently trying to get the files in an api service like this:

```
return this.http.get('../assets/exercises.json')
```

but when I run the website on azure I get a 404 error 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add your own web.config.Its in the documentation of Angular: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

```
<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /></staticContent>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143147/not-running-angular-4-applicationon-from-azure-properly

Comment: Should I be adding this file just to my source folder and running ng build --prod or should I be putting it in the dist folder after the build?

Comment: The file should be added to your source folder, then ensure that you include it as an asset to be delivered within your application, via the angular.json or angular-cli.json file.