# angular app's routing not working when deployed using Azure Static App

Tags: angular, azure, azure-static-web-app

I used  ng build --prod to product ethe dist folder locally
then I created a storage account in azure and turned on "Static App"
Then I uploaded the contents of dist/xxx folder to $web folder
but when I navigate to any route I get

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

things I tried

1. set $web to blob(anonymous) access
2. added file staticwebapp.config.json at same level where package.json is and build and uploaded the files again to container
3. used routes.json file

for staticwebapp.config files i used following

```
   {
"navigationFallback": {
"rewrite": "/index.html",
"exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
}
}
```

and

```
{
"navigationFallback": {
"rewrite": "index.html",
"exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
}
}
```

and

```
{
"navigationFallback": {
 "rewrite": "index.html"
}
}
```

Normally when others having similar issue they are able to navigate to a page and when they refresh they see this problem. but in my case i get this error as soon as i navigate first.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqV2L.png

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft Documentation,

> _routes.json that was previously used to configure routing is deprecated. Use *staticwebapp.config.json* as described in this article to configure routing and other settings for your static web app.

[`Fallback routes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes):

Example code that returns `/index.html` for all static file requests.

```cs
{ 
"navigationFallback": { 
"rewrite": "/index.html" } 
}
```

The [Example configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file) from the MS Documentation.

For further information look the similar issue fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46147365/18935775).

Comment: already used it as mentioned in the question but didnt worked.

Comment: You can also use this [video tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/azure-tips-and-tricks-static-web-apps/how-to-configure-routing-in-azure-static-web-apps-6-of-16--azure-tips-and-tricks-static-web-apps) from Microsoft if that is a preferred medium for you.

As for the original post, it looks like they may have just been missing the `.json` suffix on their configuration file. The file should be `staticwebapp.config.json`

Comment: Having `.json` or not made no difference for me ... neither solved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to move the file into the dist folder at build time. (angular.json file assets property)